# Android ListView simple_list_item1 is transparent

Tags: android, kotlin, android-xml

I am using List View to show some strings. The list view expands over view items. I am using android.R.layouts.simple_list_item1 but the backgroud is transparent so the items that should be hidden by the list are visible and the list's text is overlayed on top of them.

How to do I need custom adapter or is there any other way?